# .NET 7 Multi-platform docker build - how to conditionally change target platform in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, multiplatform

I have a Dockerfile for a .NET7 app which I am building with [docker buildx](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/#building-multi-platform-images) for both linux/amd64 and linux/arm64. This works all fine.

How I would like to optimize my build based on [this sample](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile.alpine-arm64-slim) to include the proper target platform on the `dotnet restore/publish` command. But I couldn't figure out so far how to do this conditionally inside the Dockerfile.

I have this so far, but of course this doesn't work since the variables from the first RUN command are not persisted to the following commands.

Any ideas are appreciated!

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env

ARG TARGETPLATFORM
ARG BUILDPLATFORM

RUN echo "I am running on $BUILDPLATFORM, building for $TARGETPLATFORM" > /log

# The following works but does not persist on to the next RUN

RUN if [ "$TARGETPLATFORM" = "linux/arm64 " ] ; then DOTNET_TARGET=linux-musl-arm64 ; else DOTNET_TARGET=linux-x64 ; fi

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore MyApp -r $DOTNET_TARGET /p:PublishReadyToRun=true
RUN dotnet publish MyApp  -c Release -o Ahs.AuthManager/out -r $DOTNET_TARGET --self-contained true --no-restore /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:PublishReadyToRun=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true

## more to follow here...
```

Comment: how? the platform args are getting set by buildx - and the values are different than what dotnet needs as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DOTNET_TARGET` variable you set doesn't keep its state once that instruction has executed because each `RUN` instruction uses a new shell. You can either persist the value to a file to be read from later or inline the setting of the variable with the commands that use it.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env

ARG TARGETPLATFORM
ARG BUILDPLATFORM

RUN echo "I am running on $BUILDPLATFORM, building for $TARGETPLATFORM" > /log

# The following works but does not persist on to the next RUN

RUN if [ "$TARGETPLATFORM" = "linux/arm64 " ] ; then DOTNET_TARGET=linux-musl-arm64 ; else DOTNET_TARGET=linux-x64 ; fi \
    && echo $DOTNET_TARGET > /tmp/rid

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore MyApp -r $(cat /tmp/rid) /p:PublishReadyToRun=true
RUN dotnet publish MyApp  -c Release -o Ahs.AuthManager/out -r $(cat /tmp/rid) --self-contained true --no-restore /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:PublishReadyToRun=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true

## more to follow here...
```